# show loading image if I clicked button using jQuery and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried out the example which is already there but the loading image or gif is not displaying when I clicked on to the button
this is the snippet which I have done.

```js
(function (d) { 
  d.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function () {
    d.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
    d.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
  };
}(document));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" >
  <br />  
  <input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="$('#loading').show();"/>
</form>
<div id="loading" img src="loading.gif" alt="" />Loading!</div>
```

Comment: `<div id="loading" img src="loading.gif" alt="" />Loading!</div>`  this is invalid . Whatever monster between a `div` and an `img` tag you wanted, won't work!

Comment: I think you have missed ">"  before img it should be like <div id="loading"> <img src="loading.gif" alt="" />Loading!</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

- Hide the image by default.
- Apply onclick() function on button something like this -

  ```
  $("button").click(function () {
  //SHOW LOADER HERE
  $("LOADER_IMG").show();

  // YOUR FUNCTIONALITY

  // Hide your loader
  $("LOADER_IMG").hide();
  });
  ```

#### Here is a sample

```js
$("#start-loader").click(function() {
  $("#loader-gif").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#loader-gif").hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#loader-gif {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="" >
  <br />  
  <input type="submit"  value="Click!" id="start-loader"/>
</form>
<img id="loader-gif" src="http://www.autopricemanager.com/img/widget-loader-lg-en.gif" alt="" />
```

Comment: i'm still not getting

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample snippet. Take a look.

Comment: once I click on the button still loading gif is not displaying. Please help me on this.

Comment: Its because the image I used is no longer available so it returned the error. Try now.