# How to display loader image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I am working with javascript, Right now i want to display "loader-image" after click on button, so how can i do this ?
Here is my image url

```
https://xxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Loading_icon.gif
```

And here is my current code

```
jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
//want to display loader (url menitoned above)
});
```

Comment: you just have to create an image with your url and display it. Where exactly do you struggle with this?

Comment: You're using JQuery, so `element.toggle()` or you can simply add a class that adds `display: none` to the element and then remove it when the button is clicked. I.e. `element.removeClass(your class)`

Comment: Are you just asking how to show an image in HTML?  For example, using an `<img>` element?  It's not clear to me where you're stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show loading image if I clicked button using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909552/show-loading-image-if-i-clicked-button-using-jquery-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the loader by default and show it whenever you press on the button like this:

```js
jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery('#loader').show();
});
```

```css
#loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="loader">
  <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47v26jax2ovrxmxvzz6eb35pjoa6j5uhmyy459oj4y&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g" alt="Loading...">
</div>

<button id="double_click_submit">Click me to load!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
  jQuery('body').html('<img src="https://xxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Loading_icon.gif">');
});
```

if you want to show it at the top of the page ( I used body but if you want to insert at the beginning of any class or id, you can use that instead)

```
jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
  jQuery('body').prepend('<img src="https://xxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Loading_icon.gif">');
});
```

Comment: loader is showing but further code (set timeout) not working

Comment: You dont need to set timeout. If you are doing ajax or other things, add a class to your img file for example <img class="loading" src="..." >, and then do jQuery('.loading').remove() when your task finishes ( on ajax success for example)

Answer (score 0):

To display a loader image after clicking on the button using jQuery, you can follow these steps:

1. Select the image element and store it in a variable:

   var loaderImage = $('', {
   src: 'https://xxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Loading_icon.gif'
   });
2. Append the loader image to the container where you want to display it:

   jQuery('#container').append(loaderImage);

Replace #container with the ID or class of the element where you want to display the loader image.

3.Add the loader image to the click event handler for the button:

```
jQuery('#double_click_submit').click(function(event) {
    // Add the code to display the loader image
    jQuery('#container').append(loaderImage);
    
    // Add the code to perform the button click action
    // ...
});
```

This will add the loader image to the container when the button is clicked.

Note: If you want to hide the loader image once the button click action is complete, you can use the hide() method to hide the image:

```
loaderImage.hide();
```